# How do I boot into Internet Recovery on a iMac?

Tags: imac, internet-recovery

i have this problem i tap on COMMAND+OPTION+R and I want to boot into Internet Recovery on a iMac and for some reason it just continues the screen and boots onto OS X Utilities. Someone help me?

Comment: How old is the iMac ?

Comment: The iMac i think i bought was in december or november 2013. It's new, anyways @Kristof, thanks it helped a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) support article:

> OS X Recovery includes a built in set of utilities as part of the
>   Recovery System. To start your computer from Recovery, restart your
>   Mac and hold down the **Command key** and the **R key** (Command-R).
>   Press and hold these keys until the Apple logo appears.

The recovery feature is limited to OS X Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite, and El Capitan.

Comment: This is the normal Recovery HD — not Internet Recovery…

Comment: @grgarside have a look at [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) article. It states that Internet Recovery will happen automatically if normal recovery is unavailable. Thus, the key combination CMD+R is still valid.

Comment: Yes, but if the Recovery HD is intact (as demonstrated by the ability to open OS X Utilities) then this won't begin the Internet Recovery process.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're holding the keys for the entire duration of the boot until the spinning globe icon. 'Tapping' the keys isn't enough — you'll need to hold them for a bit (longer than the normal Recovery HD).